# Spring security REST authentication with Spring social

Tags: rest, token, spring-social, spring-java-config, spring-security-rest

I am creating an application where user can login by username and password or by facebook with spring social. I've taken an example from
[this tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/), but it's configured for Spring MVC not for REST.

Author creates special UserDetailsService and assign it to the authentication manager builder.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

At this point I think everything is okay. UserDetailsService has method to find user by user id.

In http configuration in security config class should I change 'form login' to http 'basic authentication' If I want to have REST application?
If I change this, Should I add correct http authorization header with each request? Or can I use token auth with standard login (by username and password, not social)? Token based authentication will cooperate with Spring social login(there is also token)?

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialContext implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("facebook.app.id"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.app.secret")
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
                dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator,
                Encryptors.noOpText()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

}
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
                //Configures the logout function
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                //Configures url based authorization
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        //Anyone can access the urls
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/auth/**",
                                "/login",
                                "/signup/**",
                                "/user/register/**",
                                "/greeting"
                        ).permitAll()
                        //The rest of the our application is protected.
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
                .and()
                    .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer())
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
        return new AppSocialUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new AppUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }
}
```